# Upgrade VS2010 Professional to Premium or Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version

I have VS2010 Professional installed

A client has recently asked me to add a Database project to the solution for the creation and deployment of databases (only available with Premium or Ultimate)

Can I buy an upgrade to the current license? if so Where?

Or can I get the Database project templates some other way and use them with Professional?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, database projects are not worth it.  I would strongly suggest you create your databases using a script, which you can easily add to your solution and which can be versioned and checked into source control just like any other type of file.

If you are resigned, you definitely need Premium or Ultimate in order to open and use a database project.  No plugin or template will change this.

You can upgrade from Microsoft or a reseller.  I believe it comes with an MSDN license, which means the path can be steep (maybe 2-2.5k for premium and upwards of 10k for ultimate).

---

Actually, back in '11 they were pretty bad.  They are definitely improving.  I'm using one now for a website that publishes to Azure.  In this form, they are pretty damned convenient.  The tooling is still lacking in 2012.  Hopefully in 2013 you'll be able to, for example, add foreign keys using the toolset instead of writing sql.

Comment: Agreed I don't think its worth it, I've put the cost to the client. If they want to pay great... Can't seem to find any where you can upgrade seem like you have to by a new license for premium, is there such thing as an upgrade license that might be a bit cheaper?

Comment: @Axe: I'm thinking you're right.  I believe (and a qualified reseller could probably tell you in a minute) you don't upgrade Visual Studio--you upgrade your MSDN license.  If you have a real MSDN license, you will probably not face as much of a cost when upgrading as you would without.

Comment: @Axe: Hey, just saw this come down the wire, it might help:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2b1504e6-0bf1-46da-be0e-85cc792c6b9d  Visual Studio 2010 and MSDN Licensing White Paper.

Comment: I totally disagree with your HO, database projects in VS provide a lot more benefits than just storing your scripts into source control. DB projects provide a new model for designing database projects. In addition to other benefits you get with DB projects, you get validation checks and easier deployment. Overall, DB projects enhance your ALM.

Comment: @HosseinAarabi: updated.  They are better now than they were before.